# Displaying values from database using checkboxes issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

I have an issue regarding displaying data from database using checkboxes. I am able to display thembut they are displayed more than once. I only need them to display once. if there are more results for the same stuff then i should display only one of them. IF i select more than one checkboxes i get something like this

```
ISO 27005:2008
NIST SP 800 - 30
OCTAVE
CobIT
CRAMM
FMEA
FRAP
EBIOS
RuSecure
ALE
Cobra
MEHARI
ISO 27005:2008
NIST SP 800 - 30
OCTAVE
CobIT
CRAMM
FMEA
FRAP
EBIOS
RuSecure
ALE
Cobra
MEHARI
ISO 27005:2008
NIST SP 800 - 30
OCTAVE
CobIT
CRAMM
FMEA
FRAP
EBIOS
RuSecure
ALE
Cobra
MEHARI
```

And I need only one result not the same results more times. I need some kind of filter or something to compare everything listed and select only one instance. Each display result is for every checkbox selected. If i select 2 of them then 2 results for each will be shown and I want just one combined result for each of them like this:

```
ISO 27005:2008
NIST SP 800 - 30
OCTAVE
CobIT
CRAMM
FMEA
FRAP
EBIOS
RuSecure
ALE
Cobra
MEHARI
```

or any other combination which meet conditions in table
Any help or suggestion about removing duplicate values? **I am a beginner at this so sorry for my language.** Ty
        This is what I've got.

```
lol.php This is where all the action is. I use if statements to check for checked checkboxes.

     <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['chkbox1']) || (isset($_POST['chkbox2'])) || (isset($_POST['chkbox3']))) {
            if ((isset($_POST['chkbox1']) && (isset($_POST['chkbox2'])))) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where identifikacija = 1 and analiza = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }
            if ((isset($_POST['chkbox1'])) && (isset($_POST['chkbox3']))) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where identifikacija = 1 and evaluacija = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }
            if ((isset($_POST['chkbox2'])) && (isset($_POST['chkbox3']))) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where analiza = 1 and evaluacija = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }
            if (isset($_POST['chkbox1'])) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT  ime FROM kriteriji where identifikacija = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }

            if (isset($_POST['chkbox2'])) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where analiza = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }
            if (isset($_POST['chkbox3'])) {
                $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where evaluacija = 1");
                while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                    $cijena = $red['ime'];
                    echo $cijena . "<br>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $upit = mysql_query("SELECT ime FROM kriteriji where identifikacija = 1 and analiza = 1 and evaluacija = 1");
            while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
                $cijena = $red['ime'];
                echo $cijena . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

html file

    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
//spajanje na server
        $spajanje = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Nije se mouÄ‡e povezati na server :("); //spajanje na server
//spajanje na bazu
        $baza = mysql_select_db("magistarski") or die("Nije se moguÄ‡e povezati na bazu podataka :(");
        ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Magistarski</title>
    </head>

    <body>


        <form action="lol.php" method="post">
            <p>
            <table width="766" height="418" border="0">
                <caption>
                    <h1>Choose...</h1>
                </caption>
                <tr>
                    <td width="203" height="203"><h3 align="left"><em>Risk Assessment</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" value="risk_id" />
                                Risk Identification<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="risk_an" />Risk Analysis<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" value="risk_eval" />Risk Evaluation<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                    <td width="194"><h3 align="left"><em>Risk management</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox4" value="risk_ass" />
                                Risk Assessment<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox5" value="risk_acc" />Risk Acceptance<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox6" value="risk_com" />Risk Communication<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                    <td width="212"><h3 align="justify"><em>Price</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox7" value="free" />
                                Free<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox8" value="notfree" />Not Free<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="181"><h3 align="justify"><em>Organization</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox9" value="sme" />SME<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox10" value="large" />Large<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox11" value="goverment" />Goverment<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox12" value="profit" />Profit<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox13" value="nonprofit" />Non - profit<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                    <td><h3 align="justify"><em>Skills</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox14" value="basic" />Basic<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox15" value="standard" />Standard<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox16" value="specialist" />Specialist<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                    <td><h3 align="justify"><em>Documented</em></h3>
                        <div align="justify"><em>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox17" value="low" />
                                Low<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox18" value="good" />Good<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox19" value="high" />High<br>
                            </em></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </p>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show" />
        </div>
    </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: try grouping the checkboxes and achieve what you want like name="chkbox[set1][]" value="value10", name="chkbox[set1][]" value="value11", name="chkbox[set1][]" value="value12", name="chkbox[set2][]" value="value13", name="chkbox[set2][]" value="value15"... etc... or even it can be chkbox[set1][subset1][] ... and... people were not able to understand your exact need ... edit your question to make it understandable.

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, you doing it wrong by checking sent data with 'if' expressions.
I think you should first get all the required fields and then compose the query. Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['gumbposlan'])) {

    $whereString = '';

    if (isset($_POST['chkbox'])){
        foreach ($_POST['chkbox'] as $value) {
            if (empty($whereString))
                $whereString .= "where `$value` = 1 ";
            else
                $whereString .= "and where `$value` = 1 ";
        }
    }

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `ime` FROM `kriteriji` $whereString";

    $upit = mysql_query($query);
    while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
       $cijena = $red['ime'];
       if ($cijena < 1)
         echo $cijena . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can make use of the checkbox value to see which checkbox was clicked or modify your checkboxes to an associative array and you can use it as key value pairs in php

Comment: Thank you Sergey, your post helped me a lot and it works perfectly!!! Thank you!!!